# how to get all properties from the existing CurlHandle object?

Tags: php, php-curl

I have such a code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, OPTION_1, value1);
***
curl_setopt($ch, OPTION_2, value2);
***
curl_setopt($ch, OPTION_N, valueN);
***
curl_exec($ch);
```

where `curl_setopt` operators are in different (sub)procedures so I need to just extract all the properties of the `$ch` CurlHandle object in a some way to check them visually before of execution of `curl_exec($ch)`.

Is there any way to do this?